# Disable the dialog that KDE gives when moving a file on the desktop

Tags: kde, 22.04, desktop-environments, lts, plasma

When i move a file on my dekstop in KDE, it asks do i want to copy it, move it, or link it.

This dialog is very annoying for me and i want to disable it. It even appear when sending files.

I didnt find a option that disables it, only the option for the right-click menu.

Here's a picture of it.[image: The menu]

How do i disable it?

Comment: Looks like there is no such setting, at least I couldn't find one too. Press `Ctrl`, `Shift` or `Ctrl`+`Shift` while dragging depending on the desired action and the menu will not pop up.

Comment: @mook765 Heres the problem, im very lazy and often forget these keys and i just want to remove it

Comment: You cannot configure it. You have several options: 1. use it as it is. 2. edit the sourcecode and compile yourself. 3. make a feature request and wait for implentation. 4. switch to a desktop environment which does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. An option is being worked on but not yet finished. See https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=154804.